# Activity details not showing previous activity message

Tags: 2013, workflow

The things to message box is not showing previous activity message of workflow always.is it a bug in Tridion 2013?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information when do you expect to see this message? There was a bug that messages from workflow activities don't show in Things To Do list straight away. Is this your case?

Comment: After finishing one activity, when you start second activity, the things to do message box is showing previous finish message some times only. even though they are manual activities. But I can see them one the bundle's workflow tab. But I wanted to see them in things to do box.

Comment: It looks like you hit a defect there. There was a hotfix for it, but for Tridion 2013 SP1. If it is a really blocking issue for your customer they can request a hotfix backport for 2013 version.

Comment: Thanks. We are in fact already on Tridion 2013 SP1. Apologies for the confusion. Do you know if the hotfix you're referring to is included in the version we're running?  Content Manager Build 7.1.0 Content Manager Explorer Build 7.1.0.66 Experience Manager Build 7.1.0.79 Update Version: Hotfix Rollup SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 - 1.

Comment: Hi Suneetha, it looks like your version should contain this fix. You can find documentation about it by http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-26578B66-FFD3-44AA-96C8-B5DB036B419B . I am not fully sure that it is your issue, but looks very similar.

Comment: Hi. I wanted to check the js files for the hotfix and compare them to what we've got in our installation. However, I can't see any download for that hotfix number listed here: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1/index.aspx or here: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1_HR1/index.aspx. Do you have any idea where we might be able to get the js files for that particular hotfix?

Comment: Hotfix management is usually done by our CustomerSupport.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow in Tridion 2013 is working perfect for me. Regarding the previous activity message it is straight forward for manual activities. But if you have introduced an automatic activity in between of 2 manual activities, then you have to handle the previous message from the code of that automatic activity. 
Here are the steps -

1. First you have to identify the last manual activity.

   private ActivityInstanceData GetLastManualActivity()
           {
               IEnumerable activityInstances = ProcessInstance.Activities.OfType().OrderBy(o => o.StartDate);

   ```
       return activityInstances.Last(a =>
       {
           TridionActivityDefinitionData activityDefinition = (TridionActivityDefinitionData)CoreServiceClient.Read(a.ActivityDefinition.IdRef, null);
           return string.IsNullOrEmpty(activityDefinition.Script);
       });
   }
   ```

   For more detail you can refer [Answer of Eric](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2251/how-to-get-previous-performer-for-workflow-activity)
2. There is a property `FinishMessage` available under `ActivityData` class to get the message provided by the User that finished the Activity.  Read that FinishMessage data and Set it as a message for the next Manual activity.

protected override void Execute()
        {
            ActivityInstanceData lastManualActivity = GetLastManualActivity();
            string message = lastManualActivity.FinishMessage.ToString();

```
        CoreServiceClient.FinishActivity(ActivityInstance.Id, new ActivityFinishData { Message = message }, null);
    }
```

Hopefully this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What ended up fixing our problem was installing hotfix 88509. You can download this from here: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/CME_2013.1.1.88509_tcm89-21580.zip, once logged in to SDL Tridion World.